# Specify source when using gem install with two sources

Tags: ruby, rubygems

We do have an internal gem server (http://my.gem.server) and at this server we store the gem foo-1.2.3.gem

Our users add this server to the gem source. Our gem source looks like::

```
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

https://rubygems.org/
http://my.gem.server/
```

So far it was working wonderfully.

Then someone at the community created the foo-0.0.1.gem

Now, when our internal clients perform a gem install, the foo-0.0.1.gem from the community is installed instead of our foo-1.2.3.gem

We have tried putting our source before the standard rubygems.org but still get the same results.

Does anyone know how can I tell gem install to get the gem from our internal source?

It would be even better if it would just hit the community source if it does not find on ours.

Answer (score 12):

You have two options:

#### Specify the source in the command

`gem install --source http://my.gem.server/ install foo`

#### Edit the `${HOME}/.gemrc` file

change

```
:sources:
  - http://rubygems.org
  - http://my.gem.server
```

to

```
:sources:
  - http://my.gem.server
  - http://rubygems.org
```

Answer (score 3):

In your Gemfile, separate all gems into source blocks:

```
source "http://my.gem.server/" do
  gem "foo"
end

source "https://rubygems.org/" do
  gem "rails"
end
```

Having global `source` lines and/or using `:source` to disambiguate can open you to security issues, as these don't actually work the way you would expect:
http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2016/10/06/bundlers-multiple-source-security-vulnerability/
Any internal gem name might get claimed on rubygems.org and suddenly get installed instead.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to @ptierno's answer, if you have a `Gemfile` or `.gemspec` you can use the `:source` parameter.

```
gem 'foo', :source => 'http://my.gem.server'
```

Which gives priority to that server for that gem only.

Comment: Thank you. I have the gemspec inside the foo gem. But the foo gem is an application in itself with its own executable and I am distributing it as a gem, not including on another. For our internal dependencies I will try this approach.

Comment: Ah yes if you are distributing it as a gem then you are right. You should mark an answer if either one satisfied your question.